# filter array of objects with less than and present date

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have objects with different dates. How I can filter out the past dates and present date. I have dates with from past and future, I want only to past dates and the current dates from the objects. I try filtering but I'm not sure what wrong I'm doing
My CODE :

```
const arr = [{
    "id": "e18dae03-99c7-4ffa-be2f-a595fc7fad15",
    "event_date": "2021-09-30T01:00:00.000Z",
    "alert_name": null,
    "alert_level": null,
    "alert_action": null,
    "alert_details": null,
},
{
    "id": "e18dae03-99c7-4ffa-be2f-a595fc7fad15",
    "event_date": "2021-10-30T01:00:00.000Z",
    "alert_name": null,
    "alert_level": null,
    "alert_action": null,
    "alert_details": null,
}
{
    "id": "765a508f-fb47-4de4-bf69-19f0db38ccfc",
    "event_date": "2021-09-17T22:03:00.000Z",
    "alert_name": null,
    "alert_level": null,
    "alert_action": null,
    "alert_details": null,
},
{
    "id": "bc07a114-43f4-49a1-bb6c-fec801aee749",
    "longitude": null,
    "event_date": "2021-11-19T07:51:00.000Z",
    "alert_name": null,
    "alert_level": null,
    "alert_action": null,
    "alert_details": null,
}
]


const filterByExpiration = () => arr.filter(({ event_date }) => event_date <= new Date());
```

Answer (score 3):

`event_date` is a string. You should convert it to a `Date` object first.

```
const filterByExpiration = () => arr.filter(({ event_date }) => new Date(event_date) <= new Date());
```

Or compare it to an ISO date string

```
const filterByExpiration = () => arr.filter(({ event_date }) => event_date <= new Date().toISOString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the node `event_date` in each node of the `arr` to date object to make comparison. As of now its a string.

Also you have to call `filterByExpiration` function. You have just defined that, it has not been called.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const arr = [{"id":"e18dae03-99c7-4ffa-be2f-a595fc7fad15","event_date":"2021-09-30T01:00:00.000Z","alert_name":null,"alert_level":null,"alert_action":null,"alert_details":null},{"id":"e18dae03-99c7-4ffa-be2f-a595fc7fad15","event_date":"2021-10-30T01:00:00.000Z","alert_name":null,"alert_level":null,"alert_action":null,"alert_details":null},{"id":"765a508f-fb47-4de4-bf69-19f0db38ccfc","event_date":"2021-09-17T22:03:00.000Z","alert_name":null,"alert_level":null,"alert_action":null,"alert_details":null},{"id":"bc07a114-43f4-49a1-bb6c-fec801aee749","longitude":null,"event_date":"2021-11-19T07:51:00.000Z","alert_name":null,"alert_level":null,"alert_action":null,"alert_details":null}];
const filterByExpiration = () => arr.filter(({ event_date }) => new Date(event_date) <= new Date());
console.log(filterByExpiration())
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings can not be compared with Dates. You need to parse `event_date`  to a `Date` using `new Date(event_date)`. The proper comparison is

```
new Date(event_date) <= new Date()
```

```js
const arr = [{
        "id": "e18dae03-99c7-4ffa-be2f-a595fc7fad15",
        "event_date": "2021-09-30T01:00:00.000Z",
        "alert_name": null,
        "alert_level": null,
        "alert_action": null,
        "alert_details": null,
    },
    {
        "id": "e18dae03-99c7-4ffa-be2f-a595fc7fad15",
        "event_date": "2021-10-30T01:00:00.000Z",
        "alert_name": null,
        "alert_level": null,
        "alert_action": null,
        "alert_details": null,
    },
    {
        "id": "765a508f-fb47-4de4-bf69-19f0db38ccfc",
        "event_date": "2021-09-17T22:03:00.000Z",
        "alert_name": null,
        "alert_level": null,
        "alert_action": null,
        "alert_details": null,
    },
    {
        "id": "bc07a114-43f4-49a1-bb6c-fec801aee749",
        "longitude": null,
        "event_date": "2021-11-19T07:51:00.000Z",
        "alert_name": null,
        "alert_level": null,
        "alert_action": null,
        "alert_details": null,
    }
]


const filterByExpiration = () => arr.filter(({ event_date }) => new Date(event_date) <= new Date());

console.log(filterByExpiration());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `event_date` is a string. That is why the comparison is giving results you do not expect. You need to convert the string into a [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date).

```js
const arr = [{
    "id": "e18dae03-99c7-4ffa-be2f-a595fc7fad15",
    "event_date": "2021-09-30T01:00:00.000Z",
    "alert_name": null,
    "alert_level": null,
    "alert_action": null,
    "alert_details": null,
},
{
    "id": "e18dae03-99c7-4ffa-be2f-a595fc7fad15",
    "event_date": "2021-10-30T01:00:00.000Z",
    "alert_name": null,
    "alert_level": null,
    "alert_action": null,
    "alert_details": null,
},
{
    "id": "765a508f-fb47-4de4-bf69-19f0db38ccfc",
    "event_date": "2021-09-17T22:03:00.000Z",
    "alert_name": null,
    "alert_level": null,
    "alert_action": null,
    "alert_details": null,
},
{
    "id": "bc07a114-43f4-49a1-bb6c-fec801aee749",
    "longitude": null,
    "event_date": "2021-11-19T07:51:00.000Z",
    "alert_name": null,
    "alert_level": null,
    "alert_action": null,
    "alert_details": null,
}
]


const filterByExpiration = () => arr.filter(({ event_date }) => {
let x = new Date(event_date);
return (x <= new Date());
});

console.log(filterByExpiration());
```